# Join Multiple tables based on value in one table

Tags: oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper, union

I have 3 Tables which I would like to join with Table_A based on the condition in Table_A as follows:

- When value in **DATA_1 column** of **Table_A** has a value "aaa", I would like to join it with data in Table1, if "bbb", I would like to join it with data in Table2.

```
Table_A     
ID  DATA_1  DATA2
------------------
1x  aaa      qwe
2q  bbb      axz
3w  ccc      qws
4b  aaa      dal
5a  ddd      qws
```

```
Table_1     
ID  DATA_1  DATA_2  DATA_Y
--------------------------
1x  aaa      qwe     wer

Table_2     
ID  DATA_1  DATA_X   DATA_Y
---------------------------
1x  bbb      qwe     wez

and so on..
```

What I have so far:

```
SELECT h.id,
       h.data_1,
       h.data_2,
       a.data_x,
       a.data_y
FROM   table_a h,
       table_1 a
WHERE  h.order_id = a.order_id
UNION
SELECT h.id,
       h.data_1,
       h.data_2,
       b.data_x,
       b.data_y
FROM   table_a h,
       table_2 b
WHERE  h.order_id = b.order_id
```

Instead of doing a union, is there a way to combine everything into one query?

Comment: "combine" doesn't mean anything in particular. This post contains nothing clear re what you want a query to do. PS [mre] PS Conditionally joining different tables is a faq. (We don't do that, we join tables to get every possible combination of a row from each, use on and/or where to keep rows we want, then select desired functions of those rows.) PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps? Join + `CASE`. See lines #17 onward.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  table_a (id, datat, data2) as
  4    (select '1x', 'aaa', 'qwe' from dual union all
  5     select '2q', 'bbb', 'axz' from dual union all
  6     select '3w', 'ccc', 'qws' from dual
  7    ),
  8  table_1 (id, datat, datax, datay) as
  9    (select '1x', 'aaa', 'tab1 qwe', 'wer' from dual union all
 10     select '2q', 'bbb', 'tab1 xxx', 'bab' from dual
 11    ),
 12  table_2 (id, datat, datax, datay) as
 13    (select '1x', 'aaa', 'tab2 qwe', 'wez' from dual union all
 14     select '2q', 'bbb', 'tab2 yyy', 'fdf' from dual
 15    )
 16  -- query which might help
 17  select h.id, h.datat, h.data2,
 18    case when h.datat = 'aaa' then a.datax
 19         when h.datat = 'bbb' then b.datax
 20    end datax,
 21    --
 22    case when h.datat = 'aaa' then a.datay
 23         when h.datat = 'bbb' then b.datay
 24    end datay
 25  from table_a h  join table_1 a on a.id = h.id
 26                  join table_2 b on b.id = h.id;

ID DAT DAT DATAX    DAT
-- --- --- -------- ---
1x aaa qwe tab1 qwe wer
2q bbb axz tab2 yyy fdf

SQL>
```

Comment: @Littlefoot..Thanks for the response, but I get an empty output when I tried this

Comment: Well ... I don't (obviously).

Comment: when I just keep 1 case statement with just one table join, it works..but when I start adding additional case /table joins, it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Maybe there are no matches. Sample data you posted is rather *generic*, it is difficult to guess the real situation. Try to switch to **outer join** and see what happens.

Comment: It's strange, I tried. left and outer joins, but I get nulls. I'm going ahead with the below:

`select h*,
coalesce (a.status,b.status) as stat
from Table_A h
left join Table_1 a on h.id = a.id
left join Table_2  b on h.id = b.id`